# Either my binary file wasn't populated or I can't read from it

Tags: c

I can't read from my bin file... The screen displays nothing as if it has nothing in it.
Did I do something wrong while trying to read from it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include  <io.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#define COLS 10
#define ROWS 500
void displayTheResult(float a[][COLS], int c){
        int i,j;
        FILE *myBinFile;


        myBinFile = fopen("c:\myBinFile.bin","rb");
         if(myBinFile == NULL){
             printf("ERROR Reading from Bin file\n");
              printf("My computer uses 1 slash after c: \n if your computer uses 2         slashes please change all the \nfopen function accordingly in the displayTheResults() function");
             pause;
             exit(-1);
        }//END if
         fread(a,sizeof(float)*COLS, c,myBinFile);
         fclose(myBinFile);
}
```

Or did I do something wrong when I wrote to it??
Originally, I was getting errors because my teacher taught me to use "ba" and then I found out through google that it was actually "ab".

I wonder if something else like that went wrong. I'm pretty sure this is exactly the way my professor taught me afterall.

I wonder what it can be. I did error checking so its hard to believe the BIN is just NULL

```
if( (_access( "c:\myBinFile.bin", 0 ))!= -1 )
   {
       printf("BIN EXISTS");
       pause;
    myBinFile = fopen("c:\myBinFile.bin","ab");
     if(myBinFile == NULL){
         printf("ERROR appending to bin File\n");
          printf("My computer uses 1 slash after c: \n if your computer uses 2 slashes please change the \nfopen function accordingly in the displayTheResults() function");
         pause;
         exit(-1);
    }//END if
     fwrite (a,sizeof(float)*COLS, c,myBinFile);
     fclose(myBinFile);

     }//end if
     else
         {
             printf("BIN NO EXISTS :(");
     myBinFile = fopen("c:\myBinFile.bin","wb");
     if(myBinFile == NULL){
         printf("ERROR Creating new  Bin File\n");
          printf(" My computer uses 1 slash after c: \n if your computer uses 2 slashes please change the \nfopen function accordingly in the displayTheResults() function");
         pause;
         exit(-1);
    }//END if
     fwrite (a,sizeof(float)*COLS, c,myBinFile);
     fclose(myBinFile);
     }//end else
```

Or both?

You guys have to believe me. Two backslashes do not work on my computer. I think my Visual Studio automatically fixes it, but for whatever reason, two backslashes are needed on other computers, while
one backslash works on my computer.  With two blackslashes I always get the null error and it is not created. But with only one backslash the file is created and I can read it if it's a text file. I will try this later on my school computer that works with two backslashes but until then, *does anyone see another problem with the code?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a backslash in a string literal do

```
"c:\\myBinFile.bin"
```

---

**Update**:

If you use *only one* backslash the compiler will issue a warning like<sup>*1</sup>

> unrecognized character escape sequence

or

> unknown escape sequence

and ignore the single backslash which will make the file's name become:

```
"c:myBinFile.bin"
```

This is the file named `"myBinFile.bin"` in the directory you started your program in, assuming the program does not call `chmod()` to change the working directory.

<sup>*1 At least VC10 and gcc do so.</sup>

Comment: My teacher taught me that but for some reason it doesnt work with 2 black slashes on my computer, i get errors. I have a save to textfile function too that works perfectly with only 1 backslash but i get errors for 2 backslashes. I dont know why my computer is just weird because 2 backslashes work on my school computer

Comment: @user3027779: You should tell us which errors you get. Probably when using to backslashes you get `EACCES` as you may not write to drive C:'s root? As this seems to be windows, you might like to call `GetLastError()` as the 1st thing on error and print out what it returned.

Comment: The error that is that the myBinFile= NULL. because the error checking if statement i made above returns "Error reading from bin file". Is there something amiss with that if statement?

Comment: @user3027779: Do as I proposed in my last comment in case of error (getting `NULL`).